# Can't start glusterd anymore - how to deinstall entirly and start from scratch?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, glusterfs

I am new to glusterfs and have today installed v 3.7.2 on two Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VMs through ppa. Before I had it installed in version 3.4.2 which I purged. I also tried to compile it, but this failed.

Now I can not start it anymore:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/glusterfs-server start
* Starting glusterd service glusterd     [fail]
```

I tried to purge it several times and reinstalled but no luck. On a fresh ubuntu 14.04 install I was able to get it to run within 2 minutes.

Is there a way to remove all files of Glusterfs from that VM instance, so I can do a fresh install of glusterfs?

Comment: Did you try changing the owner of that file to the one you're trying to run it as?

Comment: I did just change the user of the volume: sudo gluster volume set <volume name> storage.owner-uid <uid> - I guess it does not have anything to do with the user glusterfs runs at. Seems to run only as root as I just found inside the docu!